# How to Strip whitespace from an Excel with multiple values in each cell

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe, strip

I have an Excel file in hand that some cells have entries with \n in them (i.e. multiple entries per cell). Others only have one entry per cell. there are 1100 rows in this file with a good portion of them having white spaces either trailing or leading entries or both. I am trying to use the strip() function to go over by column or by mapping but the output file split the entries in those multiple-entry cells into separate cells.

[image: here is the table in hand]

```
df=pd.read_excel('<path>\space_removal_test2.xlsx',header=1)
col_names=[<list of Excel column names>]
for i in range (0,len(col_names)):
  df[col_names[i]].str.strip()
```

and here is the output table:
[image: output]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does the issue happen before or after you apply `strip()`?

Comment: I guess so. But still, from the output file it seems that the strip() function has not even been executed (some rows show white spaces still present)

Comment: Strip removes whitespace from the beginning and end of a string, not all white space.